# Replace list element with class instance

Tags: python, list, class, list-comprehension

I have a class that transforms list like [1, 2] into symbols. It take 2 positional arguments that correspond to each of the elements in the list. I am making another function that takes in argument a list such as this one:

`lst = [[1,2], None, [1,1]]`

and transforms it into a list that has the symbols ◇ ◯ instead of the sublists. I made this code to do this but it tells me that list indices must be integers, not list.

```
newlist = [SymbolClass(l[l][0],l[l][1]) if l is not None else l for l in lst]
```

How should I change my code to make it work?

Comment: I want to take the first and second elements of each sublists to use as arguments in the class but I'm don't think that using l[l][0] is correct.

Comment: why not simply use `l[0]` and `l[1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to index the list using `l`, but `l` is a list element, not an index. Try

```
newlist = [SymbolClass(l[l][0],l[l][1]) if l is not None else l for l in range(len(lst))]
```

By the way, `l` is a not such a great single-character variable name, since it often looks like number `1`.

However, there's no need to use an explicit index. A cleaner way to write this would be

```
newlist = [SymbolClass(x[0],x[1]) if x is not None else x for x in lst]
```